# What are the values given by the android phones accelerometer?

Tags: android, android-sensors

The X,Y and Z values given by accelerometer - what are they exactly? Are they the values of acceleration vector in x, y and z axes?

What do the negative values mean? Do they signify deceleration? Or do they mean that the acceleration is in the direction of the negative axes?

Comment: try this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel).... Math :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the acceleration on the x y and z axes, where z is out of the screen, x is left to right, and y is bottom to top.  The units is m/s^2.

Negative values-  it means both.  According to physics, deceleration and acceleration in the negative axes are the same thing.

One thing to keep in mind-  it measures acceleration, not motion.  Motion at a constant speed will read 0.  Stopping will actually read a high reading, as you're decelerating.

Comment: So, if I move my phone in the positive x axis and suddenly stop, will the acceleration be -ve or +ve? And if I move the phone in the negative x axis and suddenly stop, will the acceleration be -ve or +ve?

Comment: If you move it from rest to a constant speed, say 5 m/s, you'll see a positive acceleration, then a 0 acceleration when you're up to speed.  When you stop moving it you'll see a negative acceleration then a 0 acceleration when you're stopped again

Comment: So, It doesn't matter which **direction** the phone is moving. Right? Acceleration is positive and deceleration is negative. Both in +ve and -ve axis.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of acceleration and deceleration.  Deceleration doesn't really exist.  You can accelerate in the +x or the -x direction.  Acceleration in the -x is negative.  Acceleration in the +x is positive.  It doesn't matter from a physics perspective (and thus from the sensor's) whether you're increasing or decreasing your velocity.

Comment: But in that case, if you think about it, when the phone is moving in -ve x axis and suddenly it stops. Then the value shown by the accelerometer has to be positive. Because the force and therefore the acceleration is in the +ve x axis.

Comment: Stopping is a negative acceleration.  Acceleration is change in speed.  Going from 5m/s to 0, even in a fraction of a second, will only happen if there's a negative acceleration.  Remember your physics-  an object in motion will remain in motion unless acted on by a force.  A force causes acceleration in the direction of the force.  So to stop, you MUST have a negative acceleration.  If you stop suddenly, it will be a large negative acceleration.

Comment: And in the previous comment, by negative acceleration I mean "an acceleration opposite to the direction of motion".  The actual sign would be positive if you were moving in the -x direction.

Comment: One last thing-  don't expect all 3 axes to be 0 when still.  The vector sum of the 3 should be 9.8 (or close to it depending on noise, calibration, and your altitude) because you're always under acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: @GabeSechan This is really a good answer. Can you please answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201292/how-to-find-the-direction-of-acceleration-magnitude-from-three-axes-components-o) also? I am eagerly waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The XYZ coordinate represents direction and position of the device at which acceleration occurred. The rotation direction and position are measured using gyroscope sensors that are found in the Android devices

x- right to left on screen

y- bottom to top

z-  from out of screen

It measures acceleration . So negative values means acceleration and accleration to the negative side .
The accelerometer values provided by the device normally includes the gravity as well.